# Are argument clauses and verbal expressions individual constants or individual variables (or perhaps individual predicate-argument constants)?

Tags: syntax, semantics, formal-semantics

I am studying first order predicate logic in the context of formal semantics for natural language. Propositions are understood in terms of predicates and their arguments. A given predicate takes 0 to 4 arguments. Two main types of arguments are individual constants and individual variables. Names are typical constants, e.g. *Hank, Sam, Jane,* etc. and variables are associated with quantified expressions, e.g. *every cat, some dog, two cars,* etc.

My question concerns the status of embedded clauses and verbal expressions. Are they to be viewed as constants or variables, or perhaps as additional predicate-argument structures. Consider first the following predicate-calculus renditions of a couple of simple sentences:

```
(1) Jack laughed.

        a. laughed = L

        b. Jack = j

        c. L(j)

(2) Jack saw Molly.

        a. saw = S

        b. Jack = j

        c. Molly = m

        d. S(j, m)
```

These translations of the two sentences into the formulas of predicate-calculus follow standard conventions: predicates are abbreviated as upper case letters and individual constants as lower case letters.

My question is directly concerned with the rendition of simple sentences containing object clauses or object verbal expressions. Intuitively, I would prefer the following analysis of a sentence containing an object clause:

```
 (1) Jane claimed Mary was present.

        a. claimed = C

        b. Jane = j

        c. Mary = m

        d. was present = P

        e. C(j, P(m))
```

Is this analysis correct? Can the object clause be rendered as shown here? If not, why not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I imagine Jlawler can answer this question.

Comment: I think you are right.